# Firebase integration with user database

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am integrating Firebase with a web app and I'm second guessing how I've approached the integration.

I am attempting something like pattern 3 from this old but seemingly relevant [article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/03/where-does-firebase-fit-in-your-app.html).

Each user upon registration to my app (separate database) will have a Firebase account created and the Firebase UID will be stored in the user database. Then on login, I have a server issuing Firebase tokens for the user.

Is it possible however, to use a single Firebase user account for the whole app and issue specific tokens with specific permissions for each of my apps users?

Thanks for any help.